# How to store multiple values in a single variable using typescript

Tags: typescript

How to Store multiple values in a single variable using typescript?

I have tried this

```
this.variable = this.data,this.res;
```

Comment: What do you intend the result of this to be? Why not use an array or an object?

Comment: this.data is clientId and this.res is one string ...i want to store these values in an this.variable

Comment: There is no way to assign multiple distinct values to a single variable.

use variable as an Array. like  this.variable =[this.data ,this.res ]

Comment: worked fine thank you sitaram9292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to store in **one variable** mutiple variables like describe. You need to use e.g an **[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** to store mutilple characteristic in a variable.

also: `this.variable = [this.data, this.res]`

As soon as you are using typescript, it's recommended to add types to your variable e.g:

```
let variable: [any, any];
this.variable = [this.data, this.res]
```

if you know the type of variables `this.data` and `this.res`, it will be clever to replace `any` keyword with this datatypes.

More about `primitives datatypes` in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)